# validation and calibration of crop yield data using conditional inference trees

Tags: machine-learning, nonparametric

I am trying to validate and calibrate the conditional inference tree model using the crop yield data, and I started by splitting my dataset into training and test sets.
After splitting, I had to predict the test set to see if the test set results were the same as the predicted ones, but unfortunately the predicted results are not true since almost all the values are similar

## Importing the dataset

dataset = read.csv("D:/DISSERTATION/MOMBA,MBOZI/Extracted_csv_data/Extracted_data_new2.csv")

#Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set

## install.packages('caTools')

library(caTools)
set.seed(123)

split = sample.split(dataset $Yield, SplitRatio = 0.7)
training_set = subset(dataset, split == TRUE)
test_set = subset(dataset, split == FALSE)

#Fitting ctree Regression to the Training set

regressor =ctree(Yield~ppt.resample+tavg.resample+SRD.resample+WOCBA.momba.resample+ppn.density2018.momba2.resample+ph.250.sd13+N.250.sd13+CEC.250.sd13+ORCDRC.250.sd13+BLD.250.sd13+slope,data=training_set)

## Predicting the Test set results

y_pred = predict(regressor, newdata = test_set)
y_pred

This predicted yield results is what I am getting